# Como posso pegar a data e hora, em angular e mandar pro BD?

Tags: angularjs

Encontrei esse código:
[função em angular pra pegar data e hora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962468/angularjs-display-current-date)

Testei ele e funciona legal.
Mas preciso pegar essa data e mandar pro banco, junto com outros dados. Como posso fazer isso?

Meu código está assim:

```
$scope.enviarMsg = function (mensagem) {

    function Time($scope){
        $scope.date = new Date();
    }
    var dte = Time($scope);

    var enviaMsg = {
        mensagem: mensagem,
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep'),
        nome: $window.localStorage.getItem('nome'),
        date: dte
    }

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgLogra.php", enviaMsg).success(function (data){

        console.log(data);
        pegaMsgsLogra();
        $scope.mensagem = {
          msg: ""
        }

    });
}
```

Print do console
[image: Print do console]

Comment: Vc está atribuindo o `dte` a date, isso não está sendo enviado no JSON?

Comment: Não @Techies, não está sendo enviado para o JSON. Veja na imagem que postei.

Comment: Não estou vendo a imagem.

Comment: Acabei de colocá-la.

Comment: Tente fazer esse teste: `date: new Date();` ao invés de `date: dte`

Comment: Foi, mas de forma estranha:
"[dia] => 2016-02-16T17:44:18.851Z"

Comment: Esse é o padrão, você terá que formatar a data de uma forma pra enviar pro BD ou então envia-la como Varchar

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas já consegui com esse site:
http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Assim tbm funcionaria:

```
$scope.enviarMsg = function (mensagem) {
    var enviaMsg = {
        mensagem: mensagem,
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep'),
        nome: $window.localStorage.getItem('nome'),
        date: new Date()
    }

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgLogra.php", enviaMsg).success(function (data){

        console.log(data);
        pegaMsgsLogra();
        $scope.mensagem = {
          msg: ""
        }

    });
}
```